# Running Ubuntu as VM on Windows 8 from HDD

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive, virtual-machine

I have Ubuntu installed on my HDD and I want to run it as a VM from inside my windows 8 which is also installed on that computer (different HDD).

**Is that possible? (And what VM software should I use?)**

Please notice:
I saw the [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) software and it is not what I want, I want that the files changed in the VM would be saved and when I boot into the Ubuntu it would work.

Comment: why? (15 char atleast..)

Comment: @Ramhound - It is absolutely possible.  Has been for around 5-7 years.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), it's free and cross-platform.
- I suggest you **do** use [disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx). After you create the VM files will be changes and saved, so no problem there.

  **Edit:** I think I've got your problem wrong. Automatically updating the HDD with Ubuntu via the VM software (any kind; I'm 99% sure) is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and create a "raw VMDK" using the built it command `VBoxManage`.  This should work booting Linux from Windows or Vice-Versa.

1. Install Virtualbox
2. Make sure the commands are added to your system PATH (I think this is automatic)
3. Open a CMD/Terminal (as admin/sudo)
4. To list your discs (use this to make sure you get the right ones) use `VBoxManage internalcommands listpartitions -rawdisk _____` _____ = Windows: \.\PhysicalDrive# (0,1,2,etc). Linux: /dev/sdX (a,b,c, etc.).
5. Now make the vmdk: `VBoxManage internalcomands createrawvmdk -filename /path/to/file.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive# -partitions X,Y -relative`  (could exclude partitions for the whole disk).

Now load that up in Virtualbox.

Sometimes you run into errors and have to try it again, or it may take a bit more research.  But that is the overall gist for you.

Take a look through the [Virtualbox Manual Chapter 09](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html), specifically the heading "Access to individual physical hard disk partitions".